# Random permutations of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In "[The maximum number of Hamiltonian paths in tournaments](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02128667)" by Noga Alon, the author states the following without proof (equation 3.1):

Consider a random permutation $\pi$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. What is the probability that $\pi(i+1)-\pi(i) \pmod{n} <n/2$ for all $i$?

The claim is that this is $(2+o(1))^{-n}$, which makes sense and seems like it should be a standard argument. Does anyone have a formal proof?

Comment: The maximum $\pi(i+1)- \pi(i)$ can be is $n-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered at MathOverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54051/random-permutations-of-z-n